# Creative Commons Data Dump Schedule

Tags: support, data-dump

Short question: Any date set for the current (2010/10) dump release?

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the last 9 months, data dump usually come in anytime between 1-10 days after the month ends. Just be patient.

When it is announced, you'll be able to find it on https://blog.stackoverflow.com

Comment: As a comment, I believe the dump isn't 'scheduled' to be released on any particular day. It just comes out when the team is able to compile and anonymize the data.

Comment: However, if they were *pragmatic programmers* they would create a script that anonymized the data, uploaded it, and posted to the blog.